# UINavigationBar disappears on modal

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a nav bar setup in Swift, it switches properly to other nav view controllers, but when I hit a button that is set to modal back to current view controller, to refresh the content, the nav bar disappears! How is this fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

> ...but when I hit a button that is set to modal back to current view
>   controller...

That does not make sense. A modal is a new view controller that gets displayed on top of the current view controller, completely obscuring it. You don't "modal back" to anything. If you want to return to a previous view controller in your navigation stack you probably want to use the `popToViewController:animated:` method, or use an unwind segue if you're getting back to the previous view controller via segues.